# How do I allow self-signed certificates to be accepted by Kestrel by using native .Net Core OAuth Authorization?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth-2.0, kestrel, self-signed-certificate

I am currently developing a Web Application that requires to retrieve data from an IDM system which in Dev Environment uses a Self-Signed certificate (I don't know the reason). It uses OAuth as Authorization method, so I am currently using .Net Core 3.1 OAuth libraries which throws a SSL Exception after successful redirection from the IDM. I was given the self-signed certificate (PFX file) from  the IDM but I don't know where to add it.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(pConfiguration.GetSection("Kestrel"));
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services
        .AddAuthentication(authenticationOptions => {
            authenticationOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            authenticationOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            authenticationOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = "the_scheme_challenge";
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOAuth(authenticationScheme: "the_scheme", configureOptions: oauthOptions => {
            oauthOptions.ClientId = pConfiguration["the_scheme:ClientId"];
            oauthOptions.ClientSecret = pConfiguration["the_scheme:ClientSecret"];
            oauthOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString(pConfiguration["the_scheme:CallbackURL"]);
            oauthOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://the.idm.dev/idm/oauth/authorize";
            oauthOptions.TokenEndpoint = "https://the.idm.dev/idm/oauth/token";
            oauthOptions.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://the.idm.dev/idm/oauth/userinfo";
            oauthOptions.Scope.Add(pConfiguration["the_scheme:Scope"]);
            oauthOptions.SaveTokens = true;
        });
}
```

Any advice would be accepted, I don't want to write all the HTTP Requests and Logic from scratch with some insecure code (like allowing any certificate to be accepted).

I've tested the code against other OpenID providers and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Gary's answer, installing the certificates seems like the best option.

But, I believe you can use BackchannelHttpHandler to set your own certificate validation.

```
.AddOAuth(authenticationScheme: "the_scheme", configureOptions: oauthOptions => {
    oauthOptions.ClientId = pConfiguration["the_scheme:ClientId"];
    oauthOptions.ClientSecret = pConfiguration["the_scheme:ClientSecret"];
    oauthOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString(pConfiguration["the_scheme:CallbackURL"]);
    oauthOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://the.idm.dev/idm/oauth/authorize";
    oauthOptions.TokenEndpoint = "https://the.idm.dev/idm/oauth/token";
    oauthOptions.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://the.idm.dev/idm/oauth/userinfo";
    oauthOptions.Scope.Add(pConfiguration["the_scheme:Scope"]);
    oauthOptions.SaveTokens = true;
                    
    //Handle the certificate checks yourself, 
    oauthOptions.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => {
            if (cert.Thumbprint == Configuration["TrustedCertificateThumbprint"])
            {
                      return true;
            }
                                
        }
    };
            
});
});
```

This is similar to other examples you may have already seen, but instead of just returning true, you can add your own checks such as certificate thumbprint or maybe the signing authority.

If you have control over the ID server you could also get a certificate with a trusted root, from somewhere like letsencrypt

Comment: I like this answer, I will try and I'll let you know

Comment: I'll take this as fully helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For .Net Core you should find that SSL trust inherits from the operating system's default trust store. This will usually be the Windows Certificate Store or Mac OS Key Chain.

My [Developer SSL Trust](https://authguidance.com/2017/11/11/developer-ssl-setup#browser) write up has some notes on this since:

- It can be common with OAuth tech to use self signed certs on a developer PC
- Configuring trust varies quite a bit between technologies
- We want to give ourselves a productive setup without writing insecure code, as you say

Comment: I will try this and the answer below since I am currently using .net core over Linux